# tex4ht doesn't display \HCode correctly

Tags: fonts, tex4ht, html

I'm using Miktex 2.9 and `tex4html`. In my file I have

```
\HCode{
<div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 770px; height: 
500px;"></div> <script > etc.
```

which yields

```
<div id="box"class="jxgbox\OT1\ss tyle="width: 770px; height: 500px;{\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \raise .2ex\hbox {$\scriptscriptstyle \gg $}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip }</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get code perfectly unchanged into the HTML File?

Is it a matter of fonts?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! you may want to read the [Markdown formating help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for further questions.

Comment: I think this is caused by the `babel` package, `"` characters are in some languages activated and some non wanted code may be inserted then. We need to see a minimal complete document

Comment: Dear Micha, awesome. I took babel out and now it worked. Thanks a lot. Christian

Comment: You don't have to take babel out, you can just disable the shorthands

Answer (score 1):

some `babel` language definition files make some characters active in order to enable shorthands, which are used for inserting some special codes. If you don't use these shorthands, you can disable them using

```
 \shorthandoff{"}
```

command issued after `\begin{document}`.

BTW, it is better to not use `\HCode` commands inside your document, as it doesn't work in PDF mode. You should use them only in the configuration files, either `.4ht` files for your custom packages, or in the `.cfg` file with local definitions. But I would need some complete example to give your better advice.